# Job execution to call existing controller action method

Tags: c#, asp.net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have two action method `DayStart()` and `DayEnd()` and I have to call `DayStart()`
at 8:05 am (Mon-Fri) and `DayEnd()` at 8:04 am (Mon-Fri) and for this the best option so far in Quartz.net but I don't know how do I call these two action method in jobExecution method.

Is there any way to achieve this?

```
public ActionResult StartDay()
{
  int userid = Auth.UserID;
  daysServices.StartDay(userid);
  return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { isdayClose = false });
}

public ActionResult CloseDay()
{
  int userid = Auth.UserID;
  int dayId = daysServices.getActiveDay();
  int shiftId = daysServices.getActiveShift();
  daysServices.CLoseDay(dayId, userid, shiftId);           
  return RedirectToAction("TokenDayAmount", "Home", new { isdayClose = true });
}

public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
  await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("HelloJob is executing.");
  //I hope something like this? DayStart();
}
```

Comment: Schedule two job trigger with separate cron expression as per your need. Follow there tutorial https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/index.html for understanding of quartz schdeduling

Answer (score 2):

You need three steps for this. First create a job

```
public class SomeJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
            DayStart(); //this is your start method
    }
}
```

Second you need a scheduler when your job will execute. You can use `Cron Trigger` to schedule your job like

```
public class SomeJobScheduler
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.Start();

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<SomeJob>().Build();
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithCronSchedule("0 05 8 ? * MON-FRI *") //This expression to schedule your job Mon-Fri 8.05 AM
        .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
}
```

You can find more about `Cron Ttrigger` [Here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html)

Third call your `Scheduler` in `Global,asax.cs`.

```
 void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     SomeJobScheduler.Start();
    }
```

Comment: Your examples are for Version 2, but OP looks to be using Version 3.